# postgresql replication have too much size

Tags: postgresql, replication

postgresql 10.14@ubuntu18.04

I have primary database and replicated database.
Problem is that the size of the directory that contains replication is too large. That is about 7TB on the other hand the directory that contains primary is 1.5TB.But the result of investigation by du of inside of these directories are look like same. Only the size of directory is different and I can not find what is the cause.

The result of du is below.

for primary database

```
du -sh database
1.5T    database
```

for primary inside database

```
du -sh *
4.0K    PG_VERSION
1.5T    base
456K    global
4.0K    pg_commit_ts
4.0K    pg_dynshmem
16K pg_logical
28K pg_multixact
12K pg_notify
12K pg_replslot
4.0K    pg_serial
4.0K    pg_snapshots
4.0K    pg_stat
4.0K    pg_stat_tmp
12K pg_subtrans
4.0K    pg_tblspc
4.0K    pg_twophase
273M    pg_wal
80K pg_xact
4.0K    postgresql.auto.conf
4.0K    postmaster.opts
4.0K    postmaster.pid
```

for replication database

```
du -sh database
7.2T    database
```

for replication

```
du -sh *
4.0K    PG_VERSION
1.5T    base
456K    global
4.0K    pg_commit_ts
4.0K    pg_dynshmem
16K pg_logical
28K pg_multixact
12K pg_notify
12K pg_replslot
4.0K    pg_serial
4.0K    pg_snapshots
4.0K    pg_stat
4.0K    pg_stat_tmp
12K pg_subtrans
4.0K    pg_tblspc
4.0K    pg_twophase
5.8T    pg_wal
80K pg_xact
4.0K    postgresql.auto.conf
4.0K    postmaster.opts
4.0K    postmaster.pid
4.0K    recovery.conf
```

Is there any way to find what is the reason?
How can I reduce the size of data that replication has?
thanks!

Comment: The PostgreSQL log file on the standby side will tell you why PostgreSQL has a problem removing old WAL files from `pg_wal`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> 5.8T    pg_wal

I think you have found the cause.

When you set up the replica, you probably copied over the pg_replslot directory, which you were not supposed to do.  So now the replica is waiting for its own cascading replica to connect to it read the WAL it is saving, but there is no replica to do that.  Delete that directory on the replica and restart the replica.

Alternatively, maybe you set archive_mode to always, but your archive_command doesn't work on the replica.

Comment: Thank you for your replay, I just could not found that pg_wal has size of 5.8TB. I misread that is 5.8GB. I have one question, that directory you mentioned is pg_wal directory? So specifically what I have to do is like this? [1.sudo service postgresql stop 2. sudo rm pg_wal/* 3.sudo service postgresql start] Is this correct? Or may be the directory you mention is pg_replslot?

Answer (score 0):

I do below to delete pg_wal.

1. connect to replication
2. drop replication slot with pg_drop_replication_slot

after that, size of pg_wal reduced gradually.